# Sequelize retorna erro durante teste de api

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express.js

Boa tarde amigos!

Criei uma api rest baseada em um vídeo do youtube usando node, express e sequelize. Quando envio um post vazio, para uma das rotas sem acesso ao banco, tenho retorno normalmente.

Mas quando envio um post para criação de entradas no banco de dados, o sequelize utiliza as credenciais do meu usuário do PC, e não os dados do usuário que eu informei no código.

me retorna o erro:
Access denied for user 'degrossoli'@'localhost'

- Rota: http://localhost:3030/create
- Conteúdo json:

```
{
  "username": "marcos",
  "password": 123
}
```

No controller tenho

```
async create(req, res) {
        const response = { ...responseModel };

        const { username, password } = req.body;

        const [, affectRows] = await connection.query(`
            INSERT INTO users VALUES (
                DEFAULT,
                '${username}',
                '${password}',
                NOW(),
                NOW()
            );
        `)

        response.success = affectRows > 0;

        return res.json(response);
    },
```

Minha connection

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const database = process.env.DATABASE;
const username = process.env.USERNAME;
const password = process.env.PASSWORD;
const host = process.env.HOST;
const dialect = "mysql";

const connection = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
    host,
    dialect
})

module.exports = connection;
```

Todo o conteúdo está em:
https://github.com/Marcosed1979/api-com-express

Muito obrigado!

[image: print do erro]

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO

Na instância de conexão estavam variáveis para os dados de acesso ao banco. Substituí as variáveis pelos dados de acesso e consegui gravar no banco com sucesso.

Ficou assim:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const database = process.env.DATABASE;
const username = process.env.USERNAME;
const password = process.env.PASSWORD;
const host = process.env.HOST;
const dialect = "mysql";

const connection = new Sequelize('bancodeteste', 'developer', 'd3v3l0p3r', {
   host,
   dialect
})

module.exports = connection;
```

Agora preciso entender como esconder meus dados de acesso. Mas já estou feliz. Primeira API funcionando!